# Reasonable thread count in game networking

Tags: java

I'm just curious as to what a reasonable number of threads is for a simple 2D mmo in Java. Is it reasonable to have two threads per connection, one for the input stream and one for the output stream? The reason I ask is because I use a blocking method on the input stream, and a workaround seems unnecessarily complex if I were to try to get around it without adding threads.

This is mostly for my own edification; I don't expect to have 5 million people playing it ever, or even 5, but I'm wondering what a good scalable solution is, and if this is reasonable for a small server (<30 connections).

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is try different and profile them. Interesting problem though. Good luck!

Comment: You might have better luck here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A server these days should be able to handle a lot of threads so you should be fine. I would focus on keeping the code simple at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have now posted to gamedev, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that one thread (input) is going to be blocking most of the time anyway, two threads per connection is more than reasonable.